# How to export artboards as jpgs using image processor in photoshop cc?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, jpg

I have 10 PSD files and each file is having 10 artboards in it. I want to export them all using an image processor to have a total of 100 jpg files not like 10 jpg files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *File > Export > Artboards to Files* and choose JPEG as the file format.  This can be recorded in an Action if required, then you could apply the Action to a whole bunch of PSDs using *File > Automate > Batch*

Comment: It works well @Billy. Querry Solved.

Comment: @Faizan Saeed- Please consider "up-voting" answers that help you learn more and also "marking as correct" the best answer- this not only acknowledges the answer's effort they put into answering you- it also helps others find answers when they search the site with similar questions.

Comment: @Kyle Sure, have done that. I'm new to this platform, thanks for your guidence.